# Parsing a string result from a query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

My sql server 2008 query returns a very long strings such as:

```
GET /maker/www/jsp/AutoForm.do?&userid=0asdasdsadasd&dest=Statusasdasdas&url=https%3A%2F%2Femea.salesforce.com%2Fservices%2FSoap%2Fu%2F7.0%2F00D300asdasdasar&id=0062000000KZHg8&getid=WS00D3000asdasdasd&menu=asdasd&if=prings&refreshopp=0 HTTP/1.1
```

I know I can do things like `left(columnname, 10)` to return the first 10 characters, but what I am really interested in is the part

```
getid=WS00D3000asdasdasd
```

More specifically, I just want the value getid is equal to e.g.

```
WS00D3000asdasdasd
```

Any tips?

Comment: Read up on SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX. There are plenty of string functions and operators in SQL Server that can help you accomplish these tasks.

Comment: Also your body says SQL Server 2008 and the tag says SQL Server 2008 R2. In this case it is largely irrelevant but in some cases it might be important to be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(8000);

SET @s = 'GET ...whatever...KZHg8&getid=WS00D3000asdasdasd&menu=...whatever...';

SELECT SUBSTRING(s, 1, COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('&', s)-1, -1), 8000))
  FROM (SELECT s = SUBSTRING(@s, CHARINDEX('getid=', @s)+6, 8000)) AS x;
```

This will also handle the case where `getid` is the last name/value pair.

CHARINDEX: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323%28SQL.105%29.aspx

SUBSTRING: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748%28SQL.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Play with this:

```
DECLARE @MyString as NVARCHAR(max) = 'GET /maker/www/jsp/AutoForm.do?&userid=0asdasdsadasd&dest=Statusasdasdas&url=https%3A%2F%2Femea.salesforce.com%2Fservices%2FSoap%2Fu%2F7.0%2F00D300asdasdasar&id=0062000000KZHg8&getid=WS00D3000asdasdasd&menu=asdasd&if=prings&refreshopp=0 HTTP/1.1',
@MySubstring as NVARCHAR(max) = '',
@StartString as NVARCHAR(max) = '&getid=',
@EndString as NVARCHAR(max) = '&menu=',
@SubStringFrom as INT,
@SubStringFor as INT

-- find the starting position
SET @SubStringFrom = CHARINDEX(@StartString, @MyString) + LEN(@StartString)

-- find the offset
SET @SubStringFor = CHARINDEX(@EndString, @MyString) - CHARINDEX(@StartString, @MyString) - LEN(@StartString)

SELECT @MySubstring = SUBSTRING(@MyString, @SubStringFrom, @SubStringFor)

SELECT @MySubstring
```

Then go and do what Aaron says and readup on CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING